# Best practise to patch Ubuntu server LTS enterprise

Tags: updates

I have 2 web servers with Apache2 installed in Ubuntu server LTS 14.04. (High availability)

And also I have 2 MySQL installed in Ubuntu LTS server 14.04  (High availability)

I would like to do security patching for both what's the best practice to patching? How frequently shoud I be patching, and there is any recommended website trust to download that?

Answer (score 0):

If you offer services to the internet, which i think you do with webservers, you should patch promptly. What promptly means depends on the value of your data and the visibility of your 
Services. You dowload the updates from canonicals repository, the packages are signed and you have to trust your os vendor, if not you should change the vendor.

Be aware that not all packages in ubuntu lts are getting long term support. Depending on your software stack you might want to consider updating to 16.04